# WiFi randomly crashing every 15 seconds

Tags: wireless, crash, troubleshooting

---

I just installed Ubuntu on my own 2 days ago. I noticed that my wifi randomly crashes every 15 seconds or so. I have no clue how to fix it whatsoever. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Thanks for viewing my question. Here's the required info:
I have tried restarting Wi-Fi, but no issues were solved. I don't have the option to connect to another Wi-Fi and the hotspot doesn't work for some reason. Also, I've noticed that as soon as the No Internet page pops up, the internet starts working again. My internet connection is the one on channel 4. I am pretty sure that the signal level isn't low because my PC is the only 2.4GHz device that has an issue. My PC is not far away from the router either. I changed my channel to 13 to see if there would be an improvement because of the higher frequency, but no luck. I just uploaded the script to Pastebin! I am not dual booting with Windows, I installed a third party for graphics and I am not sure about updates. Pastebin link is https://pastebin.com/C2dnhUrc. The first solution is correct! I just want to thank the community, especially Raffles who tried many things to get my Wi-Fi working again! If I encounter anything else, I will notify you.

```
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp5s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlxd03745c121bc  Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: F4:F6:47:06:55:90
                    ESSID:"Yettel_065590"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie =30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A000110104400010210470010BC329E001DD811B28601F4F647065590103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    Quality=0/100  Signal level=4/100  
          Cell 02 - Address: 60:32:B1:2B:01:34
                    ESSID:"Novak"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie =30180100000fac020200000fac02000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A000110104400010110470010000000000000100000006032B12B0134103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Cell 03 - Address: 3A:6B:1C:0D:88:65
                    ESSID:"Stefan&Ana"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                    Extra:wpa_ie =dd160050f20101000050f20401000050f20401000050f202
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:rsn_ie =30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Cell 04 - Address: 5C:76:95:85:E4:01
                    ESSID:"Dejanovic"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie =30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020c00
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD310050F204104A000110104400010210470010BB6A092D42380024C8808E1A7AA9C294103C0001031049000600372A000120
                    Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Cell 05 - Address: C4:69:F0:C5:5D:34
                    ESSID:"Jovan"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:wpa_ie =dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2040050f20201000050f202
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:rsn_ie =30180100000fac020200000fac04000fac020100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD2C0050F204104A000110104400010210470010138140001DD211B2ADEFC469F0C55D2D1049000600372A000120
                    Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Cell 06 - Address: 20:AB:48:32:AE:2C
                    ESSID:"TS-8Z2a"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:wpa_ie =dd1a0050f20101000050f20202000050f2040050f20201000050f202
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Extra:rsn_ie =30180100000fac020200000fac04000fac020100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD2C0050F204104A000110104400010210470010138140001DD211B2BD0720AB4832AE231049000600372A000120
                    Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Cell 07 - Address: B4:1C:30:A7:C4:DA
                    ESSID:"ZTE_A7C4DA"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.457 GHz (Channel 10)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:144 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie =30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
```

```
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-36-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: GNOME 42.9
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: ASUSTeK model: PRIME A320M-K v: Rev X.0x
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: 4029
    date: 11/30/2018
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: AMD Ryzen 3 1200 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Zen rev: 1
    cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 2 MiB L3: 8 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1414 high: 1550 min/max: 1550/3100 boost: enabled
    cores: 1: 1358 2: 1550 3: 1375 4: 1375 bogomips: 24750
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: nvidia
    v: 535.113.01 bus-ID: 07:00.0
  Device-2: Logitech Webcam C270 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 3-3.2:5
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: nvidia
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2
    v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 535.113.01 direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP107GL High Definition Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 07:00.1
  Device-2: AMD Family 17h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 09:00.3
  Device-3: Logitech Webcam C270 type: USB driver: snd-usb-audio,uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 3-3.2:5
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.2.0-36-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: ASUSTeK PRIME B450M-A driver: r8169 v: kernel port: f000
    bus-ID: 05:00.0
  IF: enp5s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: TP-Link TL-WN722N v2/v3 [Realtek RTL8188EUS] type: USB
    driver: r8188eu bus-ID: 3-4:4
  IF: wlxd03745c121bc state: up mac: <filter>
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 223.57 GiB used: 19.51 GiB (8.7%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: A-Data model: SU630 size: 223.57 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 218.51 GiB used: 19.51 GiB (8.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 511 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (1.2%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 2 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swapfile
Sensors:
  Message: No sensor data found. Is lm-sensors configured?
Info:
  Processes: 283 Uptime: 2h 9m Memory: 7.67 GiB used: 3.1 GiB (40.4%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A Packages: 1822 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13
```

Comment: Better change your Wi-Fi device

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. We need a lot more information in order to help you and I am assuming you are new to Ubuntu. Please open a terminal with CTRL+ALT+T.. enter the following commands verbatim in order. `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt install inxi` then once it has installed, `inxi -Fxz`. Now copy and paste the information that it returns into your question.

Comment: Your TP-Link device is recognized. Can you show us using the System Monitor Resources tab how this is crashing every 15 seconds? You just need to take a screenshot after a few minutes and edit it into your question. Have you tried resetting your Wifi or tried connecting to a different Wifi?

Comment: Please show us `iwlist scan` in your question. I'm looking at the [Github page](https://github.com/ivanovborislav/rtl8188eu) for your driver and there could be some clues. We have to eliminate the possibilities one by one. Note that the driver has been tested up to 5.19 kernel and should be okay up to kernel 6.3

Comment: I see a problem, you are receiving 7 different WiFi signals of which 3 are on CH 1, 2 on CH 7, 1 on CH 4 and 1 on CH 10. It's not really an Ubuntu problem, rather a WiFi problem. Type `iwlist chan` in your terminal and see which one is yours, or identify your SSID in the list above. Channels should [not overlap](https://infogalactic.com/info/IEEE_802.11#Channels_and_frequencies). Go into your wifi router and manually set the channel to 12 and see if this helps. I think channel 13 and 14 are not available in Europe. Overlapping occurs frequently in apartment buildings and office blocks.

Comment: However, if yours is the one on channel 4, then overlapping is not the problem, but the signal level is low.

Comment: Don't give up. Run the script at the end , it will create a file called `wireless-info.txt` in the location you run it. Sensitive information is not included. It is very comprehensive and you can look at it yourself, and upload it to pastebin for us to look at. `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info `

Comment: Can you put the pastebin link into your question and please tell us if you are dual booting with Windows. Tell us if you Checked the "Download updates while installing Ubuntu" box and the "Install third-party software for graphics..." box when you did your installation.  Also try booting into a live session and see if it does the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enter the following two commands in a terminal.

`sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

and then

`sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`

Explanation:

Your system is automatically using power saving for the network device (see below), we will turn off power saving and see if this corrects the problem. If not, we will look at a different driver.

> ###### NetworkManager config
>
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
>
> [connection]
>
> wifi.powersave = 3